# Script to install Anaconda and update conda

Tags: shell, zsh, anaconda, exec

I want to write a shell script (zsh) that does the following:

1. Installs Anaconda via Homebrew.
2. Adds conda to PATH in `.zshrc`.
3. Updates conda base environment.

I have come up with the following solution:

```
# Installing Anaconda
if [ ! -d /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/anaconda ]; then brew install --cask anaconda; fi

# This adds conda to your PATH in .zshrc and makes sure that you can now use conda and activate conda environments
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh

# Sourcing zshrc
exec zsh

# Update conda base environment
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

The problem is, that `exec zsh` replaces the current shell, so the conda update does not happen.

Is there a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `exec zsh`? Why not use `source ~/.zshrc` instead? Like this:

```
# Installing Anaconda
if [ ! -d /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/anaconda ]; then brew install --cask anaconda; fi

# This adds conda to your PATH in .zshrc and makes sure that you can now use conda and activate conda environments
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh

# Sourcing zshrc
source ~/.zshrc

# Update conda base environment
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```